# Paypal scheduled Cancel Agreement

Tags: php, paypal

I want to cancel an agreement, however I do not want to cancel it right away as it will be on a Grace Period i.e.

User subscribes on 1st of march - agreement made

User cancels agreement 1st may - (agreement should now be scheduled to cancel on 31st of May)

if User resumes - agreement is reactivated
else cancel on may 31st

This is my current code

```
            $agreementStateDescriptor = new AgreementStateDescriptor();
            $agreementStateDescriptor->setNote("Deleting the agreement");

            $agreement   = Agreement::get($agreementId, $this->_api_context);
            $agreement->cancel($agreementStateDescriptor, $this->_api_context);
```

I am aware of the suspend and reactivate method, however i would prefer this solution. Thank you

Comment: So, what is your question here?